# Default height for section header in UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to set the height of the first header in my UITableView. For the other headers I want them to remain the default height. What value/constant can I put in place of "someDefaultHeight" in the code below?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return kFirstHeaderHeight;

    return someDefaultHeight;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: why dont you try different values till you getone that you are happy with?

Comment: @Daniel - if Apple ever decides to change the default row height value then I need to ensure that my app does not hard code this value (to some arbitrary amount). It's best to pull this information out of a constant if it is declared somewhere.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

In IOS 5.0 onwards you can return UITableViewAutomaticDimension in most of the delegate methods.  Its at the bottom of the documentation page

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == CUSTOM_SECTION)
    {
        return CUSTOM_VALUE;
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: hmm.. As for me `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` returns `-1` (hardcoded const) and I don't see any sections at all in my `UITableView`.

Comment: why `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` shows -1 when `NSLog` it?

Comment: This only works when you area using: `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` if you're implementing the `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` method, this does not work.

Comment: It's worth noting, if you implement this and the estimate delegate method and return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` it will have a zero height.

Comment: @SuperSaiyen - It does work with `viewForHeaderInSection` you just need to set `estimatedSectionHeaderHeight`

Comment: In my case, it worked after i set self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = MY_VALUE; in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 51):

From checking the defaults in my app it looks like for a grouped table the default is a height  of 22 and for a non-grouped table the default is a height of 10.

If you check the value of the property sectionHeaderHeight on your tableview that should tell you.

Comment: Thanks... I'll hard code it to this. Although I do wish there was a constant for this value.

Comment: You have these backwards. `UITableViewStyleGrouped` is 22 and `UITableViewStylePlain` is 10.

Answer (score 26):

Actually do the trick :)

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
        return kFirstSectionHeaderHeight;
    return [self sectionHeaderHeight];
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `return [self.tableView sectionHeaderHeight];`, or better yet, `return [tableView sectionHeaderHeight];`.  However, both return -1 for me, perhaps because I'm not using a nib or storyboard.

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of completeness: in iOS7+ the height for grouped style section headers is `55.5` for the first and `38` for following headers.
(measured with DCIntrospect)

Answer (score 5):

For swift 4.2 you should return UITableView.automaticDimension

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the correct answer is here, but neither 10 or 22 appears to be the correct height for a grouped table view in iOS 5.  I'm using 44, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235838/uitableview-section-header-height-for-non-grouped-table) question, and it at least appears to roughly the correct height.

Answer (score 2):

To get the default height, just let `super` handle it:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return kFirstHeaderHeight;

    return [super tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section];
}
```

Comment: `[super tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section];` returns 0 for me, perhaps because I'm not using a nib or storyboard.

Comment: This only works if you are subclassing UITableViewController.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == CUSTOM_SECTION)
    {
        return CUSTOM_VALUE;
    }
    return [tableView rowHeight];
}
```

Comment: i think you mean `return [self sectionHeaderHeight];`

Comment: @TMB `[self sectionHeaderHeight];` produces an error.  Did you mean `[tableView sectionHeaderHeight];`?