# UITableView section header height for non-grouped table

Tags: uitableview, header, height, iphone-sdk-3.0

Greetings! I know that **UITableView** **sectionHeaderHeight** is only used for grouped tables, but I'll ask anyway (in case there's some way to do this that isn't obvious) ...

Is there a way to change the section header height (and with it, the font/size) for a **NON**-grouped table?

Hoping "yes" or at least a "maybe" ... but fearing it might be a "no". Have at it, folks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes.

Use this delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 44;
}
```

Of course, change as appropriate. There's of course the one for footer as well:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 44;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course, I tried that in iPhone OS 3.0, but it didn't seem to work. It would just stay the same height. However, it's working just fine in 3.1, so I suspect we chalk this one up to "bug fix" or "pilot error" on my part. (Always happy to admit if it's the latter, but I'm just not sure _why_ it wasn't working earlier if this isn't a bug fix. Even if I had sectionHeaderHeight in play, it would be overridden by tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:. Hmm ...)

Answer (score 1):

At least since iOS 9 (tested) **UITableView.sectionHeaderHeight** is working for plain table views (non-grouped) as well!

You will get the default header height (usually 22.0).

Of course the table views delegate might have customized this default value in its **tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:** method.

The following code snippet gives the height of a defined section header:

```
CGFloat headerHeight = self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight;
if ([self.tableView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:)]) {
    // possibly custom header height
    headerHeight = [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView heightForHeaderInSection:indexPathForCell.section];
}
```