# Returning CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude for UITableView section header causes crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios9, ios10

I made an app for iOS 8 which uses grouped `UITableView` for one of its page. There are multiple sections in it that uses `CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude` (or `CGFloat.min` in Swift 2 and below) for section header and footer height to remove the "default" space. Everything went well until the app run in iOS 9 and 10, where it crashes with this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'section header height must not be negative - provided height for section 0 is -0.00000'

Somehow, any value under `1` (except the rounded `0`) is treated as a negative - and using `1` as return value will make the header / footer space appears again.

Is there any workaround to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So is CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude treated as negative, or is any value under 1.0 treated as negative?

Comment: yes, and I don't know why :|

Comment: Have you tried returning just `0`? That works for me

Comment: Returning `0` will make the space on the header / footer...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have tried several values for the `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)`, and found out that:

- `leastNormalMagnitude` and `leastNonzeroMagnitude` will be treated as minus (hence the crash).
- Zero will make the TableView return the default height as header / footer.
- Anything between zero and one will be treated as a minus.
- One will make the TableView return the default height.
- Anything more than one (e.g 1.1) will set the header / footer to the actual height.

I ended up using `1.1` for solving my problem.

Hope this will help someone out there!

Comment: I don't understand how you solved your issue by setting 1.1.
If you set the height to 1.1, you still get non-zero space for your section header right ?

Comment: @Salah yes, I ended up filling the 1.1 space with a view that uses same background color with the table view.

Comment: This is just sad behaviour.

Comment: @JakubTruhlář and undocumented, on top of that... but well, life goes on :)

Answer (score 4):

We've experienced the same running on iOS 9 using Swift 5 running Xcode 10.2. It turns out if you return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude or CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude in estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection / estimatedHeightForFooterInSection, it will crash on iOS 9 devices.

You can still return leastNormalMagnitude or leastNonzeroMagnitude in heightForHeaderInSection / heightForFooterInSection.

As edopelawi pointed out above, any value less than 1 will be treated as negative, and 1 will be treated as the default grouped section header/footer height. We ended up returning 1.000001 as the estimated height if devices are running iOS 10 or below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        return self.tableView(tableView, heightForHeaderInSection: section)
    } else {
        return max(1.000001, self.tableView(tableView, heightForHeaderInSection: section))
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
        return 10
    }
    return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue if I set section header height with:

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
```

But if I set my Controller as delegate (UITableViewDelegate) for my table view and implement:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}
```

then it works

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my issue was occurred with the `UITableviewDelegate` set, without setting the tableView's `sectionHeaderHeight` and `estimatedSectionHeaderHeight` manually :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude` is what you need!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still crashed with that value :(

Answer (score 0):

If you implement viewForHeader and viewForFooter you don't have to make any cheat.

I personally return 0.1f when I want to hide the header and/or the footer for example.
This example will completely hide header and footer with no space to fill, from that you can add your custom logic.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.1f;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.1f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return nil;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nil;
}
```