# UITableView setting heightForRowAt is CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude , but it's crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My tableView setting

```
appTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
appTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and then I setting cell's height

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   if indexPath == kFirstCellIndexPath && category == .overtime {
     return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude // it will crash
     return 0  // it will not crash
   } else {
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   }
}
```

when I reload tableView, but it is crash ,Why?

Comment: what is the error log ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude for UITableView section header causes crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246153/returning-cgfloat-leastnormalmagnitude-for-uitableview-section-header-causes-cra)

Comment: because CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude will be return minus value so.

Comment: @KKRocks Can you explain the detailed point?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42768712/3901620

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
```

with

```
  return  CGFloat(FLT_MIN)
```

in `heightForRowAtIndexpath` method of the table view.