# Remove space above grouped UITableView in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

How do you remove the space above a grouped UITableView?

[image]

Comment: Here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932711/how-to-remove-the-blank-space-at-the-top-of-a-grouped-uitableview/22185534

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the space by adding a UIView to the table view `.tableHeaderView` property i.e.

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
```

`CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude` gives you the least positive number i.e. less than or equal to all positive numbers, but greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use this delegate method to set height of header section to minimum:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.1
}
```