# Weird gap at top of table view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have made a timer app:

I changed deployment target to iOS 10 earlier and when running iOS 11, everything works fine, but when I run iOS 10, it glitches - there is a large gap between the navigation bar and the table view and my info buttons are messed up.

Pictures:

[image: Table view gap at top glitch]

[image: Info buttons I made normally fine & look circular but messed up here]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1200880/7245977

Answer (score 0):

Is the top of your table view under the bottom of the navigation bar? If that's the case, you need to make sure the view controller does not adjust the content inset of the table view. For iOS 10, set the property of your view controller:

```
    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

For iOS 11, set the property of the tableView (scrollView)

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    }
```